# Query Plan Optimizer Questions

Tags: apex, soql, query, developer-console

I have used 2 filters where both are inclusive. However one was indexed and the other was not. Because of the non indexed field, I assumed a full table scan would be used. However, the screenshot still shows indexed query.

If you have LDV's, and the cost of a query is over 1, does salesforce return a result? From my understanding Salesforce does not perform queries where the cost > 1.

```
select id from contact where email = 'test@test.com' and psa_report__Resource_Name__c = 'Project Resource 1'
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Queries are optimized to use the lowest cost first, so as the Query Plan shows, it will first find all records that match by email, and then filter those for the second criteria. If you had used "OR" instead of "AND", it would have resulted in a full table scan.